# A ring of polynomials is isomorphic to a set of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{R}\left[ X \right]$ be a ring of polynomials over the set of real numbers. Every element of the set $f\in \mathbb{R}\left[ X \right]$ can be uniquely represented as a finite sum $f=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{{{a}_{k}}{{X}^{k}}}$, where ${{a}_{k}}\in \mathbb{R}$.

Let's define a set $P$ as all the possible mappings $\left\{ g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\left| \exists n\in \mathbb{N}:g\left( x \right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{{{a}_{k}}{{x}^{k}}} \right. \right\}$.
Let $\phi $ be a mapping $\phi :\mathbb{R}\left[ X \right]\to P:\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{{{a}_{k}}{{X}^{k}}}\to \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{{{a}_{k}}{{x}^{k}}}$.

In order to prove that $\phi $ is an isomorphism I need to prove that $\phi $ is injective.
I know this result is pretty straight forward.
I tried to show that if $f,h\in \mathbb{R}\left[ X \right]$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{{{a}_{k}}{{X}^{k}}}=f\ne h=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{{{b}_{k}}{{X}^{k}}}$ then there is as least one $i$ such that ${{a}_{i}}\ne {{b}_{i}}$. We have $\phi \left( f \right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{{{a}_{k}}{{x}^{k}}}$ and $\phi \left( h \right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{{{b}_{k}}{{x}^{k}}}$. If $\phi \left( f \right)=\phi \left( h \right)$ then $\phi \left( f \right)-\phi \left( h \right)=0$ but we already know that at least one ${{a}_{i}}\ne {{b}_{i}}$, therefore, $\left( {{a}_{i}}-{{b}_{i}} \right){{x}^{i}}=0$. I intuitively feel that my proof is somewhat incorrect.

Comment: If you are viewing $P$ as a set of polynomials, these are literally the exact same set, with the indeterminate renamed from $X$ to $x$. What are you actually trying to prove? And where is this problem from? (for example, I find it hard to believe that that set $P$ is defined this way in a textbook)

Comment: It seems, from the proof, that the problem is to prove isomorphism between formal polynomials and the set of functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that they represent.

Comment: You are likely misunderstanding what you are being asked to prove; the $P$ you describe should not be considered as a set of polynomials but as a set of functions. So you want to show that if $f, h \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ (note this should be $\mathbb{R}[X]$ not $\mathbb{R}[x]$) with $f \neq h$, then the **functions** $\phi(f)$ and $\phi(h)$ must be different, that is, there is a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(f)(c) \neq \phi(h)(c)$.

Comment: Are there strings attached to the 'isomorphism?' I know that sometimes authors call some specific morphism an isomorphism if context is clear. If there are no strings attached, i.e., the isomorphism is a bijection, then it suffices to construct the obvious inverse and show that the proper compositions are the appropriate identity functions.

Comment: @William An isomorphism is always a bijection, let's not confuse things needlessly.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Maybe I was unclear. I was just wondering if Gabriele had to prove bijection AND some other condition, or just bijection alone.

Comment: @William I think the question is very clear that we are looking for a bijective ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is wrong in your sketched proof of injectivity. The "direct" meaning of injectivity is that if $f(x) = h(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ then $a_k = b_k$ for all $k=0,1,2,...$ One could also restate it as a contrapositive: if $a_k \ne b_k$ for some $k=0,1,2,...$ then $f(x) \ne h(x)$ for some $x \in \mathbb R$. It looks like you have mixed together bits of the "direct" meaning and the "contrapositive".

There is a nice proof of injectivity using calculus, by proving that if $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k$ then each coefficient $a_k$ is completely determined by the function $f$ itself:
$$a_k = \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}
$$
So if $f=h$ then $a_k=b_k$ for all $k$.